# Is there a shell command to pick the n-th line?

Tags: shell

Is there a shell command to pick the n-th line of a string ?

Example:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

pick line 2.

**UPDATE:** Thank you so far. With your help, I came up with this solution for a string:

Pick the 2nd line:

```
echo -e "1\n2\n3" | head -2 | tail -1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ head -n filename | tail -1
```

where 'n' is your line number. But it's a little inefficient, launching 2 processes.

Alternatively `sed` can do this. To print the 4th line:

```
$ sed -n 4p filename
```

[This forum answer](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/sed-display-text-on-specific-line-of-text-file-397405/) details 3 different methods for `sed`

```
# print line number 52
sed -n '52p' # method 1
sed '52!d' # method 2
sed '52q;d' # method 3, efficient on large files
```

Comment: Great, thank you. How exactly does the `'52p'` option work ? I couldn't figure it out from the manual.

Comment: @JohnThreepwood: it's very simple: `-n` means "don't print automatically" and `52p` means basically "for line 52: print it"

Answer (score 1):

```
head -4 a.txt | tail -1
```

To print the 4:th line in a. txt.

Comment: @Qiau: not all implementations of `head` support `head -4`. Some would require `head -n 4` -- I think that is more portable.

Comment: "No it's not personal, I just happened to find something else you wrote to complain about!". If you really DID CARE, you would pick on the accepted answer as it will be the one people look at first.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle: And as answer "on subject": Try `head (GNU coreutils) 8.5` (Debian for example). Or head shipped with OS X Mountain Lion. Works there too. But I'm sure you can find hundreds of obscure versions that doesnt. I guess there are UNIX/Linux dists that doesn't even have `head`! OMG! DOWNVOTE!

Comment: @Qiau: Don't panick... Overall and on balance, you didn't get an downvote by me, only upvotes  :-)  I admit I had looked at the accepted answer first, but I didn't see it had the same weakness.

Answer (score 1):

Using `gawk`:

```
gawk -v n=3 'n==NR { print; exit }' a.txt
```